# How to update the field value to "false"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: firestore db]
Firestore database. How to update the field value to "false" (above picture) in javascript?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, could you please include in your question the code which you have tried. What are you using? Is it web v8 or web v9?

Comment: You can't update an element in an array in Firestore. You will have to: 1. Load the document into your application code, 2. Update the array in your code, 3. Write the entire array back to the database.